# Why was the man not charged as a malicious witness(zamem) in Deuteronomy 22?

Tags: law, deuteronomy

It said when a man takes a wife and finds,out that she is not a virgin she shall be put to death

Deuteronomy 22:20-21 NIV

> :If, however, the charge is true and no proof of the young woman’s virginity can be found,21:she shall be brought to the door of her father’s house and there the men of her town shall stone her to death. She has done an outrageous thing in Israel by being promiscuous while still in her father’s house. You must purge the evil from among you.

But if the man is found to be lying he shall be fined a certain amount

Deuteronomy 22:19 NIV

> :They shall fine him a hundred shekels of silver and give them to the young woman’s father, because this man has given an Israelite virgin a bad name. She shall continue to be his wife; he must not divorce her as long as he lives.

According to the law a malicious witness(zamem) was suppose to receive the same punishment he had intended the other party to receive

Deuteronomy 19:19 NIV

> :then do to the false witness as that witness intended to do to the other party. You must purge the evil from among you.

After producing the tokens of virginity why was the man not charged as a malicious witness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the false report or "Shem-Ra" שֵׁם רָע Bad-Name against a Wife אִשָּׁה "Ishah" in [Deuteronomy 22:13-14] was denounced by her father, could reciprocal justice related to the Ed-Sheker עֵד־שֶׁקֶר (from Deuteronomy 19 verses 18-19) be enacted against the wife's malicious husband?

After the "father-of" אֲבִי "the-girl" הַנַּֽעֲרָה disproves the Ed-Sheker of the detestable husband with evidence of her innocence, the father-of-the-girl אֲבִי הַנַּֽעֲרָה would have to establish the קֶשֶׁר Kesher | Relationship of Ishah אִשָּׁה = Ish אִישׁ , since Deuteronomy 19 verse 21 defines damages associated with reciprocal justice : עַיִן בְּעַיִן "eye for eye" , שֵׁן בְּשֵׁן "tooth for tooth" , יָד בְּיָד "hand for hand" , רֶגֶל בְּרָֽגֶל "foot for foot" ... [Not "Ish for Ishah"].  If the Father of the girl demands more justice than the law of [Deuteronomy 22:18-19] then the final Judgement would be decided by הַכֹּֽהֲנִים הַֽלְוִיִּם The Levitic Priests based on Deuteronomy 17 verse 9.